# Is there an open-source tool for drawing OPC UA graphical notation?

Tags: opc, opc-ua

Do you know about some drawing tool that supports the **Graphical Notation** described in the OPC UA standard Part 3 Annex D?

The notation is similar to UML but has some extra elements that map nicely to the OPC UA information model (like different types of references). This is an example of the notation:

[image: An example of the notation]

It would be great if it was free, ideally open-source. Thanks.

Comment: The diagrams are usually drawn in Visio, but I don't know of any open source tool.

Comment: @Jouni Do you know whether there are some shapes/templates available for Visio that are used for these diagrams?

Comment: UAModeler from Unified Automation ? https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uamodeler.html

Comment: I have seen some, but I don't know if there are any publicly available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to get the official OPC UA Specification Graphical Notation:

This requires a Windows PC with Office Word and Office Visio installed.

1. Download the Companion Specification Template (free after registering):
   https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/opc-ua-companion-specification-template/
2. Open the Word Document
3. Scroll to a Diagram in the first part of the document. Since all the drawings are embedded visio files, you can double-click to edit the graphical notation inplace.
4. Then select the graphical notation and copy/paste it to a new Visio Document
5. Use any part of the copied notation to create your own drawing

Answer (score 2):

Yes Draw.io is good choise.

I have found recently one shape library for draw.io on [github](https://github.com/cpipero/OPC-UA-Draw.io-Library) by **Costantino Pipero**. There are already created standard shapes.

[image]

You can just download .xml file and in draw.io you can import it in File -> Open Library from -> (choose from where you want import)

If you want edit this library or create your own - [tutorial](https://about.draw.io/draw-io-training-exercise-9-create-your-own-custom-library/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Windows PC and Visio installed you can simply download the official Visio shape library form the OPC Foundation website: https://opcfoundation.org/guidelines-and-templates/

Answer (score 0):

You can use draw.io: https://www.draw.io/

It's not an explicit tool for OPC UA but it supports all shapes, arrows and styling options.